# Онлайн логгер и анализатор

Tags: .net

Подскажите какие есть онлайн сервисы (наподобие google analytics) для standalone приложения (.NET). Т.е нужен сервис на который я смогу настроить логирование и анализ.+У сервиса должен быть веб-интерфейс где можно будет глянуть логи. P.s azure stream analytics не подходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл сервис Loggly и использовал log4net-loggly из NuGet , если вдруг кто столкнётся с такой задачей.

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/212941)

Comment: @Air это не дополнение к вопросу, это ответ.

Comment: Andrew, не могли бы вы привести небольшой пример кода для решения этой задачи? Он бы пригодился будущим читателям вопроса.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ок... я всегда пропускаю  вопросы ответы, в которых не разбираюсь, но в данном варианте или я был невнимателен или просто не понял... ок  следующий раз буду внимательней

Comment: @NickVolynkin у этого сервиса есть хорошая документация с примерами , так подробно описано как и что юзать для разных платформ и языков.